# Overriding login_authenticate_start: how to fail with specific message?

Tags: login, authentication

I have an extension that uses a 3rd party authentication system for EE3. It's working great overriding `login_authenticate_start` but I'm stuck on some logic for when the 3rd party auth fails: how to fail gracefully?

I know in this function I can `exit()` to stop the login, but it's not pretty. If you just `exit()` you get a white page.

How do I reject the login gracefully (i.e. back to the login page) and provide my own text for the explanation text? (much like when you fail a login normally as depicted below)

[image: failed login example]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this? This is how EE passes messages to a redirect. https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/development/legacy/libraries/session.html#flash-data-for-redirects

Comment: That's likely relevant however this seems to be helpful for passing data between pages _that you control_. The login page isn't part of my extension, I'm just taking over one step in the process.